# Heavy vs light queries

Tags: database, performance

When you have an application that is constantly querying a database for information, in terms of performance, and database usage, is it better to have one big query that pulls in all the data at once or is it better to have a bunch of smaller query's that pull in the data one at a time. Does it matter?

Im trying to figure out if I should query my entire class once any value in the class is requested. Or to only query individual values as they are needed.

Comment: Im not entirely sure what you mean by that?

Comment: @MichaelTaylor3D It depends. Each small query requires a connection to the database. It may be better to have a single larger query that only requires a single connection, but without more information about your schema or queries, we can't really help.

Comment: heavy/entire class = 'chunky,' pull everything you want in one chunk, minimize 'chat.'  light/as needed = 'chatty,' keep taking to the server in little requests.

Comment: also http://shajisethu.blogspot.com/2006/01/chatty-or-chunky-interfaces.html

Comment: @njk what kind of information do you need? I have a php script that manages all the querying and sends it back through REST. So im assuming every time I send a query request it has to initiate a brand new connection. What Im mostly concerned about is that the people that maintain the database have to pay per usage. I want to optimize my code to use the least usage possible while still pulling in the needed data.

Comment: @MichaelTaylor3D If others are paying per usage, then you should pull as much data as you can at once and work with it locally.

Comment: @njk I beleive that was the answer i was looking for, if you can post it as an answer ill mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If others are paying for your usage, I would recommend pulling as much data as you can in a single connection and work with it locally. However, I don't know what 'usage' is defined as. It could be connections, bandwidth, operations, etc.